# XML Extract child elements as elements

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following XML from a Rest API call:

```
<opens type="array">
 <open>
  <account-id>123</account-id>
  <campaign-id type="integer">10000</campaign-id>
  <contact-id type="integer">302315</contact-id>
  <browser>Other</browser>
  <recorded-at type="dateTime">2016-03-12T12:52:07-05:00</recorded-at>
  <contact>
     <id type="integer">302315</id>
     <email>someone@mailnoone.com</email>
     <memberid>1255252</memberid>
  </contact>
 </open>
 <open>
  <account-id>123</account-id>
  <campaign-id type="integer">10000</campaign-id>
  <contact-id type="integer">302326</contact-id>
  <browser>Other</browser>
  <recorded-at type="dateTime">2016-03-13T12:52:07-05:00</recorded-at>
  <contact>
     <id type="integer">302326</id>
     <email>secondopen@mailnoone.com</email>
     <memberid>1255248</memberid>
  </contact>
 </open>
</opens>
```

and I am trying to get this as an output

```
<opens type="array">
 <open>
  <account-id>487</account-id>
  <campaign-id type="integer">504084</campaign-id>
  <contact-id type="integer">396056515</contact-id>
  <browser>Other</browser>
  <recorded-at type="dateTime">2016-03-12T12:52:07-05:00</recorded-at>
  <contact-id type="integer">396056515</id>
  <email>ldrmtrl@mac.com</email>
  <memberid>145773617</memberid>
 </open>
 <open>
  <account-id>123</account-id>
  <campaign-id type="integer">10000</campaign-id>
  <contact-id type="integer">302326</contact-id>
  <browser>Other</browser>
  <recorded-at type="dateTime">2016-03-13T12:52:07-05:00</recorded-at>
  <contact-id type="integer">302326</id>
  <email>secondopen@mailnoone.com</email>
  <memberid>1255248</memberid>
 </open>
</opens>
```

What should my XSLT look like? The contact element will appear only once inside each Open element. Sometimes there may not be any open element. I see some examples in this site that are similar but couldn't exactly figure this out.

Thanks,
Ranchi

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the answer. When I use the following XSLT it loads it correctly.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
 <xsl:template match="*">
  <xsl:element name="{name()}">
   <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
   <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:element>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="//contact">
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Please provide any better or faster performing solution if applies.

Thanks,
Ranchi